# How to prevent parallel execution of two downstream jobs triggered from two different upstream jobs

Tags: jenkins

[image]

I have Job A which triggers two downstream jobs, say Job B and Job C. These two downstream jobs executes in parallel on master node. Job B then triggers another job say job 1 on a slave node and job C triggers job 2 on the same slave node almost at the same time. Number of executors configured on this slave node is 1 as i don't want job 1 and job 2 to run concurrently. Job 2 gets queued since job 1 is already running on that slave node. But when job 1 finishes execution, job 2 runs into executor starvation and gets stuck.

Issue:- Job 2 is running into executor starvation and gets stuck.

Is there any way in which once job 1 finishes execution, job 2 starts running instead of getting stack. i have also tried Throttle concurrent builds plugin but still the issue persists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several plugins that allow resource management:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/External+Resource+Dispatcher

Some block the job from executing, others have the job "wait" for the resource (while job is running).

You would have to setup your Job1 and Job2 to use some resource, so that they can wait for one another.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Used Exclusion-Plugin. Job 2 waits for Job 1 to complete and as soon as job 1 finishes, Job 2 starts executing.